# Conversion SHA1 byte array from java to PHP

Tags: java, php, variables, type-conversion, sha1

I have to update one web app from Java to PHP and I found some hard problems...
The big problem is to convert the SHA1 from Java to PHP because someone before me developed an browser extension that need a particular auth code to work... i can't change the plugin, i have only to convert the web app from java to php...

This is the code:

```
 private static final byte[] SecretKey;

  public static String AuthCode(String url) {

    byte[] urlBytes = url.getBytes("US-ASCII");

    byte[] concatenated = new byte[SecretKey.length + urlBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(SecretKey, 0, concatenated, 0, SecretKey.length);
    System.arraycopy(urlBytes, 0, concatenated, SecretKey.length, urlBytes.length);

    byte[] hash = HashTools.calculateHash(concatenated, "SHA1");
    return CodecTools.encodeBASE64(hash);
  }

  static {
    SecretKey = new byte[] { 18, -15, -48, 73, 54, -115, 34, -87 };
  }
```

Now, I found very hard convert the SecretKey from byte to something else in php.. because php don't have byte variable... and i read that sha1 in php is different from java.

In PHP I can't make a sha1 of a array chars, it want only a String...

(the other stackoverflow answers suggest only how to change Java code to be equal to php.. I need that the PHP code should be equal to Java...)

I hope in someone that help me because I don't really know Java...

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple <kbd>string</kbd> as byte container.

for example, if you want to store the secret key:

```
$secretKeyArray = array(18, -15, -48, 73, 54, -115, 34, -87);

$secretString = '';
foreach($secretKeyArray as $k => $v) {
   $secretString.= chr($v & 0xFF); // trim to 8 bits (for the negative values)
}
```

Now you have the secret key stored in `$secretString`.

***Edit:***

the concatenated array would be:

```
$concatenated = $secretString . $url;
```

and then

```
return base64_encode(sha1($concatenated, true));
```

Comment: Thankyou... but... how to handle the `urlBytes`? in Java there's `.getBytes("US-ASCII")`, in PHP no...

Comment: There's something strange here... with this `secretkey = array(-26, 68, -35, -71, -92, 66, 66, -6, -78, -15, -18, 79, 74, 96, 58, -46),` and this `url= "http://localhost:8080/sdweb/install/plugin?goto=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsdweb%2Fload%2Fform"`
I have this `auth code=GXkt5cLC9+ioIewWBwArNuXmev0=` in java... in PHP no.... it's different...it's `fviaimu5Mu6X/4d51bzVDM3KbzI=`

Comment: do you pass the url "as is" or url-decoded? Try to debug step by step to catch the difference.